# Collections Sort to sort both ArrayLists the same

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

My program has to use the Collections sort method to sort the ArrayList of Strings lexicographically but each String has a corresponding integer value stored in a separate ArrayList. I want to sort them both the same so the integer values stay with the correct Strings. And if you know a better way to store both values I'm all ears.

```
public class a5p1b {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[^a-zA-z]+");
        // ArrayLists to store the Strings and the frequencies
        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> intLst = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //loops through as long as there is user input
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String str = input.next().toLowerCase();
            // if the list already has the string it doesn't add it and it
            // ups the count by 1
            if (lst.contains(str)) {
                int index = lst.indexOf(str);
                intLst.set(index, intLst.get(index) + 1);
            } else {
                // if the word hasnt been found yet it adds it to the list
                lst.add(str);
                intLst.add(1);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Do you want them sorted numerically or lexicographically? But maybe you could store them in a map.

Comment: Use a map from strings to integers, then sort the keys and pull out the values in sorted order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting your abstractions wrong. If that string and that number belong together, then do **not** keep them in **two** distinct lists.

Instead create a class (or maybe use one of the existing [Pair](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java.util.pair%20example) classes) that holds those two values. You can then provide an equals method for that class; plus a specific [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), that only compares the string elements.

Finally, you put objects of that class into a **single** list; and then you sort *that* list.

The whole idea of good OO programming is to create helpful *abstractions*!

For the record: as dnault suggests, if there is really no "tight" coupling between strings and numbers you could also use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (to be used as `TreeMap<String, Integer>`) to take care of sorting strings that have a number with them.

Comment: TreeMap<String, Integer> might also be a viable alternative.

Comment: @dnault I had the same idea while walking the dog; but thanks for you input; I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
inList.sort(Comparator.comparing(i -> i.toString());
```

Although, I don't think the two lists is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Map to associate each unique String key with an Integer value.

Then you can invoke Collections.sort on the map's set of keys returned by `keySet()`.

Additionally, if you use a SortedMap such as TreeMap, it is not necessary to sort the keys. However that solution may not fulfill the requirements of your "Assignment 5 Problem 1b."